# how to create and new object when using map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

I have a question about following, I have to create list2 from list1, so I have applied solution 1 which worked well. However I had to make it separate function for unit test. After changing it, I was not able to make it like solution 2. If I print returned value, it says undefined for 3 elements of array. Does anyone have some advice for this problem? I have tried hard but I can't still solve it.

```
var list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' } 
];

var list2 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java',
    greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python',
    greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
  },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby',
    greeting: 'Hi Madison, what do you like the most about Ruby?'
  } 
];
```

**Solution 1**

```
let greetings1 = list1.map(person => {
  return Object.assign(
    { firstName: person.firstName },
    { lastName: person.lastName },
    { country: person.country },
    { continent: person.continent },
    { age: person.age },
    { language: person.language },
    {
      greeting: `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${
        person.language
      }?`
    }
  );
});
```

**Solution 2**

```
function greetDevelopers(list1) {
  const greetings = list1.map(person => {
    Object.assign(
      { firstName: person.firstName },
      { lastName: person.lastName },
      { country: person.country },
      { continent: person.continent },
      { age: person.age },
      { language: person.language },
      {
        greeting: `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${
          person.language
        }?`
      }
    );
  });
  return greetings;
}
```

Comment: solution 2 does not return other than `undefined` in `map`. just add `return`. btw, what is the real question?

Comment: Why do you use `Object.assign` instead of just writing: `{firstName: person.firstName, lastName: person.lastName, country: person.country, continent: person.continent /*, ... */ }`? What do you expect from that?

Comment: As described in question, I expect list2. I am so stupid, I forgot to return it. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
function greetDevelopers(list1) {
  const greetings = list1.map(person => {
    return Object.assign( // add return before Object.assign
      { firstName: person.firstName },
      { lastName: person.lastName },
      { country: person.country },
      { continent: person.continent },
      { age: person.age },
      { language: person.language },
      {
        greeting: `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${
          person.language
        }?`
      }
    );
  });
  return greetings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the object and add just the new property by taking a copy of the old properties.

```
let greetings1 = list1.map(person => Object.assign(
    {},
    person,
    { greeting: `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${person.language}?`}
));
```

Solution 2 does not return an other value than `undefied`, because you do not return the created object.

```
function greetDevelopers(list1) {
    const greetings = list1.map(person => {
        return Object.assign(
        //^^^^
            // ...
        );
   });
   return greetings;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this can be good solution which makes codes much simpler, thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

solution 2 does not return `Object.assign`, hence, `undefined` is returned. Further you can simplify your code to following

```js
var list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' } 
];

function greetDevelopers(list1) {
  return list1.map(o => ({...o, greeting: `Hi ${o.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${o.language}?`}));
}
console.log(greetDevelopers(list1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are dealing with data structures and the functions that alter them, that means [Abstract Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), and this is mostly a synonym for [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS). In javascript there are three main ways to work with classes or objects:

- [Prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)
- [The module (revealing) pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)
- [ES6 classes](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-classes/)

You are also doing unit testing, you need to have a clear separation between the application code and the testing code. In the following code i will use prototypes, for simplicity.

```js
// APPLICATION CODE
function Person(data) {
  Object.assign(this,data);
  };
  
Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  return `Hi ${this.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${this.language}`;
};

// TESTING DATA
var inputList = [
  { firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, language: 'Java' },
  { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' } 
];

// TESTING CODE
const createAndGreet = (data) => {
  const p = new Person(data);
  data.greeting = p.greet(); 
  return data;
};

console.log(inputList.map(createAndGreet));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach:

```js
const input = [{
    firstName: 'Sofia',
    lastName: 'I.',
    country: 'Argentina',
    continent: 'Americas',
    age: 35,
    language: 'Java'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Lukas',
    lastName: 'X.',
    country: 'Croatia',
    continent: 'Europe',
    age: 35,
    language: 'Python'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Madison',
    lastName: 'U.',
    country: 'United States',
    continent: 'Americas',
    age: 32,
    language: 'Ruby'
  }
]

// objOf :: String -> Any -> Object
const objOf = prop => x => ({ [prop]: x })

// concatObj :: Object -> Object -> Object
const concatObj = x => y => ({ ...x, ...y })

// pipe :: Array (a -> Any) -> a -> b
const pipe = xs => x => xs.reduce((x, f) => f (x), x)

// greeting :: { firstName::String, language::String } -> String
const greeting = ({
  firstName,
  language
}) => `Hi ${firstName}, what do you like the most about ${language}?`

// appendGreeting :: Object -> Object
const appendGreeting = o => pipe ([ 
  greeting, // (1) Generates the greeting
  objOf ('greeting'), // (2) Creates an object owning greeting property
  concatObj (o) // (3) Concats the input object with the "greeting" one
]) (o)

const output = input.map (appendGreeting)

console.log (output)
```